# Good races/class combination for tank, healer and damage dealer in WoW

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am new to WoW and I invited two friends to play WoW with me and we are going to take the tank, damage dealer and healer roles for partying.

However, I thought to be a Tauren paladin and one friend chose Undead mage (my other friend will start playing tomorrow). The problem is that he was born at the other side of the world.

How can we choose three **good race/classes combinations** that fulfill the three roles and that **are born close to each other** so we can party since the beginning of the game?

I would like to know the combination for both Horde and Alliance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So there's two real issues here.

### How to start near your Friends

The first is a question of start location. In WoW, this is wholly dependent on your race. As of Cataclysm, each race has it's own unique start location, which means that **if you pick different races, you will not be 'born together'**.

**HOWEVER:**

It is extremely easy to get to the capital cities, and you reach these at about level 5, after completing your starting zone. And once you're in *one* capital city, it is very easy to get to any other capital city.

**So my advice:** if you don't mind playing separately for the first five levels (should take about an hour or so, if you go slowly), *play whatever race you want*.

All roads lead to **Orgrimmar**, the Orc capital -- if your friends play Undead, there's a zeppelin in the undead capital to take you to Orgrimmar, and if your friends want to play a Blood Elf, there's transport from the blood elf capital to the undead capitol, and from there you can get to Orgrimmar the same way. Tauren also have a zeppelin (from their capital) to Orgirmmar as well, these days. `Thanks, Powerlord`

The Alliance has similar arrangements with Stormwind as the hub.

### On the Tank / DPS / Healer trinity

First off, every class can do damage. While you might hear grumblings on the forums that one class or the other is 'better', Blizzard generally does a good job at keeping people even. Never let someone else convince you the class you picked is 'bad'. Blizzard does not make 'bad' classes. But everyone has a personal preference, and invariably these preferences clash, and so you get the "Nerf Wars" chorus, summed up by the pithy:

> "Dear Blizzard--
> Paper is fine. Please nerf Rock.
> Sincerely, Scissors"

#### Damage Dealers

While all classes *can* deal damage, there are four classes that can *exclusively* deal damage. That is to say, they cannot tank or heal -- they simply don't have the options. These classes are the following:

- Mage
- Warlock
- Hunter
- Rogue

#### Healers

Likewise, there are 4 classes capable of healing, totaling 5 unique subsets of healer. They can cast heals on other players, resurrect dead friends, and otherwise mitigate death and damage. These classs are as following:

- Priest (Discipline)
- Priest (Holy)
- Paladin (Holy)
- Shaman (Restoration)
- Druid (Restoration)

#### Tanks

Finally, there are 4 classes capable of tanking. This means mitigating damage, taunting mobs into hitting you first (and the party later), and other 'defender-y' things.

- Warrior (Protection)
- Paladin (Protection)
- Druid (Feral Combat)
- Death Knight (Blood)*

The Death Knight is a special case, as they are not available to players just starting out. The class becomes available when one of your characters reaches level 55.

#### Class Conclusions

As you may have noticed, Paladins and Druids showed up on both the "Tank" and "Healer" lists. They are good candidates if you or your friends want to potentially fill any of the roles.

My personal suggestion is that selecting any of the 6 'hybrid' classes is a good choice for starting character, just in case you want to switch roles later. The other thing is that though these classes *can* spec for these roles starting at level 10, they generally won't be needed while leveling up via quests etc. Three DPS specs will likely progress much faster than a dedicated tank, DPSer, and healer. The exception is if you want to run a dungeon (called an instance) with your pals, where the three roles are strongly encouraged (more so at the highest levels).

However, starting at level **30**, your character can purchase the ability to alternate between two separate talent configurations (often referred to as 'dual spec') which means you and your pals can stick as 3 DPSers while questing, and break into your roles when you go dungeon diving. Depending on the exact class, this may require at *least* carrying around a spare shield in your inventory.

### In Conclusion (TLDR)

WoW is a very social game, and any three classes will work well together. Likewise, it is quite easy to meet up, so don't let starting in different areas prevent you from playing what you want.

It's *your* character. **Play what you want**. WoW will make it work.

There's little worse than sinking time and money into a character you're only half invested in.

Comment: You don't even need to wait the first five or so levels, although if you do then you won't be beat up for your lunch money quite so often.

Comment: Yes, there is a Zeppelin from Thunder Bluff to Orgrimmar.

Comment: @Xantec - except that Goblins, Worgen, Blood Elves, and Draenei have isolated starting areas, and in the case of the foremost two, are completely instanced and unreachable by other races.

Comment: @Raven thats true, forgot Gobs/Worgs. if you choose them you'll be a few levels over level 5 by the time you get out. For Blood Elves and Draenei it is a simple matter to go to and fro from their starting zones, or to get a portal to somewhere else.

Comment: @Xantec if they just started playing, I doubt they will have easy access to a portal. There are players more then happy to give new players a free port to meet up with friends, but they could be waiting long time to find one.

Comment: @Xantec - additionally, I know quite a few of Bloodmyst / Azuremyst quests are race-specific. It's one of the reason the starting zones don't show up in the "Complete X quests in Zone Y" achievements.